# ipn listener paypal

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I am working on simple shopping cart, one problem is driving my crazy IPN listener is not working

When I make a payment I get redirected back to the thank you page and those values are printed out.

`thankyou.php` those posts down below printed out and there are lots of posts variables as well .

```
[address_status] => confirmed

[payment_status] => Completed

[payer_status] => verified
```

The problem is with my IPN listener is not working.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysqlphp.uphero.com/paypal_ipn.php">
```

**This is the script on my paypal_ipn.php down below:**

```
// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") 
    die ("No Post Variables"); ------> 

// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    // Read the post from PayPal
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

    $curl_result=$curl_err='';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req); 

// Check that the result verifies and sending email before doing anything i just wanted to make sure that this script is working but i don't receive an email

    if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
        $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
        mail("eagleeyes26@hotmail.com", "IPN interaction verified", "$req", "eagleeyes26@hotmail.com" );


}
```

Comment: When you say "not working", can you tell if the script is ever being called, or is the problem in the script itself? Are you seeing any errors in your server error log?

Comment: (this isn't an answer, btw, just a comment) Paypal can be confusing, their documentation is a mess! I am about to work with the IPN today, if I learn anything I'll come back and check on your question here. As it stands, I don't know enough about the process to diagnose your trouble.

Comment: ok, thank you bro, i really appreciated, and i will if i find something i will post back to you.. thank you one more time

Comment: hello Chris i successfully get PDT=Payment Data Transfer and below here is the variables                                  
Array  
[mc_gross]=>40.00                                                   [address_status] => confirmed 
[payment_status] => Completed
[payer_status] => verified
[txn_id] => 55096177K9979392K) 
this is means i successfully i bought the product therefore i get PDT,how ever PDT is not secure,i must use IPN as well,i have mentioned above this is the page where pay pall will send ipn
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysqlphp.uphero.com/paypal_ipn.php">

Comment: ipn means Instant payment notification, paypal supposed to send me data back after a buyer decided to buy product , unfortunately i don't get any post data from paypal to my paypal_ipn.php listener page. however i have set up this URL in my sandbox to get instant payment notification back from paypal when there is valid transaction, i hope to i made myself clear. sorry Chris my english is bit hard to understand...

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

http://microlabs.altervista.org/paypal-ipn-listener/

and work fine, feature automated email with attached download purchase, site in italian language but you can translate in footer